# Game of Life, C++ - Polymorphic Array (And maybe Pointers)

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm having trouble with some code, dealing with polymorphism.

Essentially I am to make a Game of Life, and as such have a driver where I create a grid of Organism pointers (the super class to actual animal classes, in this case, Ant).

In my driver, I create a new Ant in the array of Organism pointers using the following code:

```
[DRIVER]
Ant *ant = new Ant(&world, GRID_HEIGHT, GRID_WIDTH);
world.setOrganism(ant,4,4);
```

Here I create a pointer to an Ant, and plop it in the world.  Here's setOrgamism function:

```
[World]
void World::setOrganism(Organism *organism, int x, int y)
{   grid[x][y] = organism; }
```

So, this code works when called from the driver.  I can make a new ant using this anywhere, no problems.

However, when I try to run this in the Ant's spawn function, I get an Access Violation error and my program crashes executing setOrganism.

Here's the code in my Ant class for the spawn function:

```
[Ant]
void Ant::spawn(int spawnX, int spawnY)
{
     Ant *newAnt = new Ant(world, GRID_HEIGHT, GRID_WIDTH);
     newAnt->setPosition(spawnX,spawnY);

     world->setOrganism(newAnt, spawnX, spawnY);
}
```

Any and all help is certainly appreciated!

Edit:

```
[World.cpp]
#include "World.h"
#include "Ant.h"
#include "Lion.h"

using namespace std;

World::~World(void)
{
}

World::World(void)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < GRID_HEIGHT; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < GRID_WIDTH; x++)
        {
            grid[x][y] = NULL;
        }
    }
}

Organism* World::getOrganism(int x, int y)
{
    return grid[x][y];
}

void World::setOrganism(Organism *organism, int x, int y)
{
    grid[x][y] = organism;
    organism->setPosition(x,y);
}
```

_

```
[Ant]
#include "Ant.h"

using namespace std;

Ant::~Ant(void)
{
}

Ant::Ant(void)
{
}

Ant::Ant(World *world, int width, int height)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
}

void Ant::spawn(int spawnX, int spawnY)
{
    Ant *newAnt = new Ant(world, GRID_HEIGHT, GRID_WIDTH);
    newAnt->setPosition(spawnX,spawnY);

    world->setOrganism(newAnt, spawnX, spawnY);
}
```

_

```
[Driver]
#include "Organism.h"
#include "Ant.h"
#include "Lion.h"
#include "World.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    World *world = new World();

    //This works
    Ant *ant = new Ant(world, GRID_HEIGHT, GRID_WIDTH);
    world->setOrganism(ant,4,4);

    //This does not
    ant->spawn(6,6);
}
```

If you need any more information, please ask!

Comment: Share the class definitions for `Ant` and `Organism`.

Comment: Could you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: The only possible sources for that error in the code you've shown us is that `world` may be uninitialized or `NULL`, or `spawnX`/`spawnY` out of range.

Comment: And to continue on the comment by @Casey: spawnX/spawnY may be out of range because you're not calling `SetPosition` on the ant you created in the [DRIVER], while the `spawn` function suggests that that is needed in your implementation.

Comment: Updated with what I hope is an SSCCE -- that being said, the problematic code seems to lie with the World classes' setOrganism.  setPosition is just the a property in the Ant so it knows where it is, in this case I've just hard-coded values for testing so that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: What is the `world` in `Ant::spawn()` referring to? It can't be the local `world` defined in `main()`. Perhaps you have a global `world` which is hidden by `main()`'s local `world` and is thus never initialised?

Comment: The Organisms, the Ant's superclass, requires a World such that it can get information from the world.

The world I create in the Driver, and every Ant, (and later Lion), will have a pointer to that world.

In this scenario, I create the Ants from the driver, and every Ant just passes the pointer to the one it will spawn.  In theory this works, but in practice -- well, this could very well be the issue, but I still can't see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown the definition of `Organism`, but from your comments, I assume it has a member `World *world`. You're passing a `World *world` into the constructor of `Ant`, but you're not using it for anything; you're not assigning it anywhere, and you're not calling any non-default constructor of `Organism` either. This means that the member `world` is most probably left uninitialised.

This in turn means that inside `Ant::spawn`, the `world` (referring to `this->world`) is either a null pointer or a garbage value (depending on how the default constructor of `Organism` initialises its `world` member). Either of these will lead to an Access violation when dereferenced - precisely what you're getting.

To fix that, make sure `Ant`'s constructor initialises the `world` member somehow - probably by passing on the `world` parameter to the appropriate constructor of `Organism`.

Comment: Couldn't see the forest through the trees -- thank you very much!  I did forget to assign the Organism's world pointer to the one being passed in - doi :p

Answer (score 0):

you didn't declare the type of grid. you just have grid[x][y] = null; you should have set it to Organism grid[x][y], and then set it later on

Comment: Umm, `grid` is in all likelihood a member of `World`, so it's probably defined in `World.h`.